# jQuery treeview plugin collapse/expand to the newly added node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery treeview plugin and the following is the example code for adding branches to the tree.

```
var newLi =  jQuery(strListString).appendTo(objParentULjQuery);
jQuery(objParentULjQuery).treeview({add: newLi});
```

After adding the new node it should be selected. How it is possible?

After that I need to expand/collapse to the newly added node. How can I do that?

// binding onclick event

$(objParentLI).find("div.hitarea").live("click",function() {

```
               //under li class to be chaged to expandable/collapsable according to the node event
               //under li div class to be changed to "hitarea expandable-hitarea" or collapsable collapsable-hitarea
               //under li span the style should be display:none;

               if($(objParentLI).hasClass('collapsable'))
               {

                    $(objParentLI).removeClass('collapsable').addClass('expandable');
                    $(objNew).removeClass('collapsable-hitarea').addClass('hitarea expandable-hitarea');
                    $(newLi).css("display", "none");                         
               }
               else if($(objParentLI).hasClass('expandable'))
                {

                    $(objParentLI).removeClass('expandable').addClass('collapsable');
                    $(objNew).removeClass('expandable-hitarea').addClass('hitarea collapsable-hitarea');
                    $(newLi).css("display", "block"); 
                }
            });
```

Please support me in this issue and let me know any questions.

Comment: which jQuery treeview plugin are you using?

Comment: * http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/
 * http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is:

```
newLi.click();
```

After the line that adds it to the tree view. Not sure what you mean by selected.

Comment: i need to select that node once the node is created